# Match a sequence of arbitrary bytes from a hex string

Tags: regex, rust

I am trying to craft a ***Regex expression to match the raw arbitrary bytes from a hex string***.

I am using the *regex::bytes* module which allows me to enforce regex on bytes and hex to decode to hex string
and I have the following code:

```
use hex;
use regex::bytes::Regex;

fn main() {
    let data = hex::decode("48656c6c6f20776f726c64").unwrap(); // Convert's "Hello World" 's hex string to raw bytes.
    println!("{:?}",data); // [72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 119, 111, 114, 108, 100] , raw bytes of "Hello World"
    let data_re = Regex::new(r"").unwrap(); // What expression should go here?
    println!("{}",data_re.is_match(&data));
}
```

What Regex expression should go in the `r""` on line 7 to match the raw bytes of the hello world hex string?

Comment: Would it not just be `r"^Hello World$"`?

Comment: If you want to match any hex code, the syntax is like `\x7F`. See: [Regex Escape Sequences](https://docs.rs/regex/latest/regex/#escape-sequences)

Comment: @cdhowie Yes but what if it was an other random string? I used Hello World as an example

Comment: @PitaJ I am trying to match a sequence of bytes not the hex code that why I am decoding the hex string from a hex string to bytes

Comment: Yes, the sequence of bytes for "Hello World" would be written as `Regex::new(r"\x48\x65\x6C\x6C\x6F\x20\x57\x6F\x72\x6C\x64")`. You can use the `\xYY` syntax to cover any sequence of bytes. What's the problem? Do you want to build the pattern programmatically?

Comment: @PitaJ Indeed, but what if it was not "Hello World" and was for example a sequence of arbitrary bytes? I used Hello World as an example

Comment: So what is your input from which you build the pattern? Is it a hex string or an array of bytes?

Comment: @Bolt Then it's not clear at all what you're asking. Are you asking how to convert `data` to a regular expression? Because that's a bit silly; you can do an equality test without the overhead of a regex engine.

Comment: If you're only looking for one sequence of bytes within another, you may want to consider using `memchr` instead.

Comment: Even though it is used to match against arbitrary bytes, you cannot create a [`regex::bytes::Regex`](https://docs.rs/regex/latest/regex/bytes/struct.Regex.html#method.new) from arbitrary bytes, it must be a string. You can use [`from_utf8`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/fn.from_utf8.html) if you think your bytes are utf-8 encoded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What Regex expression should go in the `r""` on line 7 to match the raw bytes of the hello world hex string?

The expression you're looking for is:

```
&data
    .iter()
    .map(|b| format!("\\x{:02x}", b))
    .collect::<Vec<_>>()
    .join("")
```

In your example, it will produce the string `\x48\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f\x20\x77\x6f\x72\x6c\x64`, but will work for arbitrary slice (or other iterable) of bytes.